# SQL syntax error php db class

Tags: php, database

I have a form which needs to be updated I get a sql error. Cant see whats going on with my sql statement in my class file. Need assistance in finding where the issue is.

```
public function update(){
    global $database;
$sql = "UPDATE ".self::$table_name." SET when = '{$database->mysql_prep($this->when)}', where = '{$database->mysql_prep($this->where)}', howmuch = '{$database->mysql_prep($this->howmuch)}', contact = '{$database->mysql_prep($this->contact)}', daytimephone = '{$database->mysql_prep($this->daytimephone)}', emailqueries = '{$database->mysql_prep($this->emailqueries)}', websiteurl = '{$database->mysql_prep($this->websiteurl)}', description = '{$database->mysql_prep($this->description)}' WHERE id='{$database->mysql_prep($this->id)}'";
    $database->query($sql);
    return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true:false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WHEN` and `WHERE` are reserved keywords in MySQL. Enclose them in backticks if you need to use those as field names:

```
`where`
`when`
```

Comment: So is `when`... its used with `CASE`

Comment: stupid formatting is messin' with yo' backicks - i fixed it up a bit, hope you dont mind :-)

Comment: @prodigitalson Yeah I just went through hell trying to make the backticks look good and keep code formatting... Thanks for editing! (-: